# Split factors with same name in dplyr

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe:

```
    structure(list(allele_freq = c(8, 11, 14, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 10, 1, 45, 48, 1, 16, 1), gene = structure(c(2L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 
6L, 12L, 10L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 14L), .Label = c("E-cadherin", 
"intergenic", "CHES-1-like", "Ddr", "mino", "mspo", "ZnT35C", 
"CG11984", "CG12301", "CG34356", "DCP2", "Eip63E", "hb", "spri"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("allele_freq", 
"gene"))
```

This shows a list of genes, and the frequencies at which that they occur in my data.

Some genes can occur more than once in the data (e.g. `intergenic` here). I am trying to plot the frequencies for each gene **without summing the `allele_freq` values for genes that occur more than once**.

Here's what I have:

```
library(dplyr)

bp_data <- bp_data %>%
    # ... some other filtering...
    mutate(allele_freq = as.numeric(allele_freq)) %>%
    transform(gene = reorder(gene, -allele_freq)) %>%
    droplevels()

  p <- ggplot(bp_data)
  p <- p + geom_bar(aes(gene, allele_freq), stat='identity')
  p
```

[image]

Here, the `allele_freq` values for all `intergenic` entries is being summed. I would like for it to be represented multiple times on my plot.

Comment: Any issue with changing the names of each `intergenic` entry to `intergenicX` where `X` is number?

Comment: @CPak - No that would be great.

Comment: You could also just do a scatterplot and that would show all the `allele_freq` that the gene occours at on the same vertical axis without having to rename anything. More information can be added by adding text to the plot at those points or chaning symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df2 <- df %>% arrange(gene,-allele_freq) %>% group_by(gene) %>%
  mutate(count = seq(n())) %>%
  mutate(gene2 = paste(gene,count,sep="")) %>%
  transform(gene2 = reorder(gene2, -allele_freq)) 

ggplot(df2,aes(x=gene2,y=allele_freq)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a dirty trick but it works

```
df %>% 
   split(.$gene) %>% 
   do.call(rbind, .) %>% 
   mutate(gene = rownames(.))

   # allele_freq          gene
# 1            1 E-cadherin.13
# 2           45 E-cadherin.14
# 3            8  intergenic.1
# 4           14  intergenic.3
# 5           48 intergenic.15
# 6            1 intergenic.16
# 7           16   CHES-1-like
# 8           11           Ddr
# 9           10          mino
# 10           7          mspo
# 11           7        ZnT35C
# 12           1       CG11984
# 13           1       CG12301
# 14           1       CG34356
# 15           1          DCP2
# 16           1        Eip63E
# 17           1            hb
# 18           1          spri
```

I say dirty because it takes advantage of the side-effect of `do.call(rbind, ...)` to enumerate identical factors/values, rather than enumerating values explicitly. (Note the number appended is the original row-number of the value)

With ggplot

```
df %>% 
  split(.$gene) %>% 
  do.call(rbind, .) %>% 
  mutate(gene = rownames(.)) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x=gene, y=allele_freq)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```